# Specify the gtk file path when using InstallScript command

Tags: dm-script

When using InstallScript command to generate gtk file, the gtk file path is always at home\AppData\Local\Gatan\Plugins. Is that possible to change the file path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,
(and actually, the folder depends on the install options: "just user" or "all users")
but it is easy enough to add script commands to copy (or move) a file after generation, once the file is generated.
However, the gtk's will only be *read* from the locations above.